# Flat $\mathbb{Z}$-modules and algebraic independence

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, flatness, transcendence-theory

I know that this question is naive, but I really want to find out if this observation is correct. 
First, let $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \dotsc, \alpha_k$ be real numbers.
Consider the $\mathbb{Z}$-module homomorphism
\begin{align*}
  f \colon \mathbb{Z}[x_1, x_2, \dotsc, x_k] &\rightarrow \mathbb{R} \,,
\\
  p(x_1, x_2, \dotsc, x_k) &\mapsto p(\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \dotsc,\alpha_k) \,.
\end{align*}
Now, we will say that a polynomial $g \in \mathbb{Z}[x_1, x_2, \dotsc, x_k]$ is unfactored if there is no polynomial $h \in \mathbb{Z}[x_1, x_2, \dotsc, x_k]$ and integer $a$ such that $g=ah$.
Let $I$ be the set of unfactored polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}[x_1, x_2, \dotsc, x_k]$.
Given the following exact sequence of $\mathbb{Z}$-modules:
$$
  \operatorname{Im} f
  \overset{g'}{\longrightarrow}
  \operatorname{Im} f
  \rightarrow
  \operatorname{Im} f / \operatorname{Im} g',
$$
where
$$
  g'(p(\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \dotsc, \alpha_k))
  =
  g(\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \dotsc, \alpha_k) p(\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \dotsc, \alpha_k)
$$
one can notice several things:

1. $\operatorname{Im} f$ is a torsion-free $\mathbb{Z}$-module (since for every real number $\gamma$ there is no integer $b$ with $\gamma b = 0$) and, therefore, a flat $\mathbb{Z}$-module.
2. Since $\operatorname{Im} f$ is flat, this sequence is pure exact iff $\operatorname{Im} f / \operatorname{Im} g'$ is flat.

However, a theorem of Kaplansky says that $A$ is a pure submodule of $B$ iff for every ideal $L$ of the ring $R$ (in this case $\mathbb{Z}$): $A \cap L \cdot B = L \cdot A$.
Using this theorem, one can deduce that a short exact sequence as above is pure, or, equivalently, $\operatorname{Im} f / \operatorname{Im} g'$ is flat iff $g(\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \dotsc, \alpha_k) \notin \mathbb{Z}$ and there is no polynomial $h$ with $g(\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \dotsc, \alpha_k) = l \cdot h(\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \dotsc, \alpha_k)$, for some integer $l$.
However, it is clear that these conditions hold iff $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \dotsc, \alpha_k$ are algebraically independent.
Knowing that a direct sum of modules is flat iff every direct summand is so, we can see that the algebraic independence of $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \dotsc, \alpha_k$ is equivalent to the purity of the sequence:
$$
  \bigoplus_{g \in I} \operatorname{Im} f
  \overset{g'}{\longrightarrow}
  \operatorname{Im} f
  \rightarrow
  \operatorname{Im} f / \operatorname{Im} g'
$$
and to the flatness of $\bigoplus_{g \in I} \operatorname{Im} f / \operatorname{Im} g'$.
It is known that rings with countably generated ideals (definitely the case of $\mathbb{Z}$) have weak homological dimension less than or equal to $2$.
Moreover, it is known that $\mathbb{Z}$ has weak homological dimension $1$.
This means that $\bigoplus_{g \in I} \operatorname{Im} f / \operatorname{Im} g'$ is flat iff the sequence above is **not** a minimal flat resolution of it.
Due to the characterization of minimal flat resolutions which uses flat covers, we get that if
$$
  \bigoplus_{g \in I} \operatorname{Im} f_{g}
  \rightarrow
  \bigoplus_{g \in I} \operatorname{Im} f / \operatorname{Im} g'
$$
is not a flat cover, then $\bigoplus_{g \in I} \operatorname{Im} f / \operatorname{Im} g'$ is flat and, therefore, $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \dotsc, \alpha_k$ are algebraically independent.
This implies that if there exists an endomorphism $s \colon \bigoplus_{g \in I} \operatorname{Im} f_{g} \rightarrow \bigoplus_{g \in I} \operatorname{Im} f_{g}$ such that the map above is equal to its composition with $s$ and there exist two elements $x_1, x_2 \in \bigoplus_{g \in I} \operatorname{Im} f_{g}$ such that $s(x_1) = s(x_2)$, then $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \dotsc, \alpha_k$ are algebraically independent (because $s$ is not an automorphism).

The reason for which I consider this result interesting is that it transforms a statement of the form $\forall$ implies algebraic independence into $\exists$ implies algebraic independence.
In other words, it sufficises to show that **there exists** a function $s$ and **there exists** some elements $x_1$, $x_2$ satisfying certain conditions, instead of proving that a statement holds **for all** the elements of the polynomial ring $\mathbb{Z}[x_1, x_2, \dotsc, x_k]$.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: And the question is...?

Comment: Whether or not it is correct. I mean, is there anything wrong or are there any mistakes?